# Who's generating this JSON Catalog files, and can I put them under git ignore?

Tags: git, visual-studio

On an existing application, I see that each time I build a file of this type is generated

[image]

I've still not understood who's generating it and if I can put this folder under git ignore...

I use Resharper and VS 2022 Pro, but I don't think it's generating them... any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: it's a .net app!

Comment: btw it seems a bug and as update of 17.4.3 it continue happening